# Neo4j - OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, configuration, spring-security, neo4j, spring-data

Trying to implement spring-security with help of neo4j but receive a lot of exception and can't find the reason. Opensuse 13, folder with db is not in use before I start application. Thanks in suggestions! What should I to provide you to clarify the question?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336) ~[BeanDefinitionValueResolver.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[BeanDefinitionValueResolver.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [HttpServletBean.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4922) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151) ~[FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[BeanDefinitionValueResolver.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:358) ~[InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[EmbeddedGraphDatabase.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90) ~[GraphDatabaseFactory$1.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199) ~[GraphDatabaseBuilder.class:2.1.2]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.createDatabase(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:50) ~[GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.class:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:42) ~[GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.class:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:14) ~[GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.class:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144) ~[FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@7d6b8a1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[LifeSupport.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335) ~[InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.class:2.1.2]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:78) ~[StoreLocker.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44) ~[StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.class:2.1.2]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1060) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.tryLock(StoreFileChannel.java:142) ~[StoreFileChannel.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:35) ~[FileLock.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:93) ~[FileLock.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:92) ~[DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.class:2.1.2]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74) ~[StoreLocker.class:2.1.2]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Jul 18, 2014 11:54:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4922)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:358)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.createDatabase(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:50)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:42)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:14)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@7d6b8a1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1060)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.tryLock(StoreFileChannel.java:142)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
        ... 47 more

    Jul 18, 2014 11:54:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /cyou threw load() exception
    java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1060)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.tryLock(StoreFileChannel.java:142)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.createDatabase(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:50)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:42)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.getObject(GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean.java:14)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4922)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

DataBase folder is created when spring autowires bean, the lock file is present.

messages.log error:

```
2014-07-18 20:54:21.232+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@7d6b8a1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /home/beaver/dev/data/cyoudb/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access): null
```

Comment: Make sure there is no other Neo4j instance (either embedded or server) running on the same directory.

Comment: Already done with it. No idea what can be wrong..but db is created by my app, so only my app should obtain lock on the db directory